# Get Temporary Link using Dropbox API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, dropbox-api

Ok so I have searched and searched and to be quite honest there isn't a lot in the way of info or tutorials for the newer version of the Dropbox API - v2 for PHP developers (very prejudice). I am trying to use the /get_temporary_link as per the API documentation. The full URL being:

```
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_link
```

I'm including in the 'headers' array the following:

```
'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token
'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
```

Again this is in the documentation and is included in a call made using the API Explorer, however the only code they provide is Python where as I am a PHP developer. I'm still getting code 400 Bad Request response. I'm doing the call from within WordPress btw so using wp_remote_post() for that.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Just to be clear as well I have tried including in the headers array and outside the following:

```
'data' => '{"path":"/test.txt"}'
```

Still nothing! Please someone help. Thanks!

Comment: Already discovered how to do it. I didn't realise I need to include the JSON part in the 'body' of the request.

Comment: For reference, whenever you get a 400 or 409 response from the Dropbox API, be sure to check the response body itself, as it will contain a more specific error message.